# What is the distribution of $aX$ when $X$ is Gumbel? What is the distribution of $-X$ when $X$ is Gumbel?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

If $X$ is a random variable distributed as a [Gumbel](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GumbelDistribution.html) with location $\gamma$ and scale $1$ (where $\gamma$ is the Euler constant)

[Hence the mean is
$$
\gamma-1\times\gamma=0
$$
and the variance is
$$
\pi^2/6\times 1^2=\pi^2/6
$$]

(1) What is the distribution of $aX$ where $a\in \mathbb{R}$? $a$ should be $>0$?

(2) What is the distribution of $-X$?

**I don't know if it is relevant, but here I'm using the definition of Gumbel as in [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GumbelDistribution.html) and [Matlab](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/extreme-value-distribution.html) (sign flipped with respect to the definition of Gumbel in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution))**

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: (1) I think that $aX$ is Gumbel with location $\gamma$ and scale that should be adjusted. Maybe the new scale is simply $a$? (2) The Gumbel is not symmetric around zero. So I'm tempted to say that $-X$ is not Gumbel But I don't know what else can be said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still a Gumbel distribution.

As with Normal distributions, the family of Gumbel distributions includes all pdfs of the form $|\beta|^{-1}f\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\beta}\right)$, where $f$ is in the family. So $X\mapsto aX$ just scales $\beta$ to $a\beta$, including in the case $a=-1$.

Comment: Thanks. But for $a=-1$ then the new scale would be $-\beta$ which is $<0$ (which is not possible, right?). Shouldn't we impose $a>0$?

Comment: What about point (2) of my question?

Comment: @STF (2) is, as explained, a special case of (1). You shouldn't worry about $\beta<0$ as long as you see the sign of $\beta$ as saying whether it's a left- or right-handed Gumbel distribution. This is an area where the situation is very different from the Normal distribution, because the pdf isn't even.

Comment: could you given a look to this other question of mine if you have some time? Thanks https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3039451/sum-of-gumbel-with-long-tail-on-the-right-and-long-tail-on-the-left