# Sum / difference of two Gumbel

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I would like your help to derive the distribution of the sum/difference of two random variables which are distributed as Gumbel.

Consider $X$ having Gumbel distribution with "long tail on the right" as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution#Related_distributions), location $\gamma$ (Euler constant), and scale $\beta_x>0$.

Consider $Y$ having Gumbel distribution with "long tail on the right" as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution#Related_distributions), location $\gamma$ (Euler constant), and scale $\beta_y>0$.

**(1)** What is the distribution of $X-Y$?

According to Wikipedia, if $\beta_x=\beta_y=\beta$, then  $X-Y$ is Logistic with location $\gamma-\gamma=0$ and scale $\beta$.

Can we say something when $\beta_x\neq \beta_y$?

**(2)** What is the distribution of $X+Y$? My thoughts:

(2.1) $X+Y=X-(-Y)$

(2.2) $-Y$ is Gumbel with location $\gamma$ and scale $-\beta_y$

(2.3) Hence ?

Comment: Sorry; I misread your question and thought the $a_i$ were locationsand $\gamma$ a scale. Having reconsidered, my technique won't address the problem you asked about, so I've deleted my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I've reformulated my question, I hope the notation is less confusing now.